# How can I loop though many URL's from the same website in order to web scrap data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try this and it works only for the first bon_ISIN. It gets the bond price for only the first bond_ISIN, but I want to be able to get bond prices for each ISIN within bond_ISIN. I want the code to insert each item within bond_ISIN into the link and print each bond price associated with each bond_ISIN. Ive pasted the code below but I realized that the forloop isnt indented when i post here. assume ive already indented the contents of the for loop when running this code.
Thanks for the help.

```
bond_ISIN=[
    "us369604bq57",
    "us26441CBG96",
    "us31428XBV73",
]

link='https://markets.businessinsider.com/bonds/dl-flr_prefsecs_1621-und_d-bond-{}'

ticker_data=dict(zip(bond_ISIN, ticker_dataframes))

for ISIN in bond_ISIN: 
    r=urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.businessinsider.com/bonds/dl-flr_prefsecs_1621-und_d-bond-us369604bq57').read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
    type(soup)
    currentvalue= soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "price-
    section__current-value"})
    print(currentvalue.get_text())
```

Comment: perhaps have a look at my [python based spider](https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/xdspider) and perhaps modify this to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Your `soup.find( ... )` call is fine.
But it does not depend on `ISIN`.

Construct the `soup` just once,
rather than doing it within a `for` loop.

Then either

1. loop over `soup.findall( ... )` results, ..or..
2. do a `soup.find( ... )` on each ISIN bond of interest.